# substraction numpy.ndarray from pandas.series

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array, shape = (15435, 1)

```
array([[-3.92473475],
       [-3.72456857],
       [-4.0962113 ],
       ..., 
       [-2.96900943],
       [-3.0485911 ],
       [-3.15411717]])
```

and a pandas series, shape  = (15435, )

How can I subtract these two?

Thank you!

Comment: `s - arr.ravel()`?

Comment: Can you give the sample output @PumpkinC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = np.array([[10],[2],[3]])
a.shape
>>(3, 1)

b = pd.Series([2,3,4])
b.shape
>>(3,)
```

Reshape numpy

```
a = a.reshape(1,3)

a
>array([[10,  2,  3]])
```

More general reshape:

```
a.reshape(1, a.size)
```

Now you can subtract

```
a - b.values
>>array([[ 8, -1, -1]])

b.values - a
>>array([[-8,  1,  1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you in performing calculations between `pd.Series` and `np.ndarray`. Remember that underlying data in `pd.Series` is held *as numpy arrays*, so these calculations are natural.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
s = pd.Series([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])

s.values - arr

# array([ 4,  2,  0, -2, -4], dtype=int64)

s - pd.Series(arr)

# 0    4
# 1    2
# 2    0
# 3   -2
# 4   -4
# dtype: int64
```